Is there any radiation similar to Bremsstrahlung in electron-electron or electron-positron scattering?
When an electron scatters on a nucleus, it emits Bremsstrahlung, which makes sense as any charge being accelerated emits EM radiation.
However, I don't remember free electrons emitting any radiation when scattering against another free electron or against a free positron (as in Møller and Bahbha scattering), the tree level Feynman Diagram for them is like this one:

So my question is: Is there really no radiation? Is this also the same in classical ED?
I'd guess that, as both has the same mass and make a symmetric movement in the CM of the system, that their radiation could interfere destructively and cause no energy to be radiated into infinity, no much differently from the effect of adding the radiative contributions of all accelerated charges of a DC current through a curved conductor.
However I'm not sure if this is actually the case and I haven't found anywhere explicitly claiming this either.

Did you search for papers on the topic? I got immediate hits for radiative corrections to bhabha scattering which includes the photon emissions lines. It's necessary to compute them when doing radiative corrections to account for divergences in the virtual diagrams.

@Triatticus I found them for a fixed material target like in the reply I got here as well. A free electron interacting with a bound electron, but this introduces some differences. I'm thinking of two electrons as in two electron beams interacting in a vacuum without any external field acting upon them, in a situation where the motion of the two electrons, in the CM frame, is going to be symmetric.

Symmetry doesn't forbid this radiation, in fact it must be accounted for since there are infinitely many photons that are radiated that would escape detection in this situation. You will in fact have radiation from all four legs of this diagram.

You are comparing apples and oranges. You show the tree diagram, but there are also radiative diagrams:

which are higher order, and hence fall under "radiative corrections".
In practice, there are two kinds: internal and external. Internal is a coherent quantum higher order process, while external is a result of the experimental set up.
For instance, if you are scattering an electron beam off the electrons in a metal foil, you need to consider processes in which the electron bremstrahlungs in the foil and then elastically scatters off an atomic electron, or it scatters and the brems on the way to the detector. There is tons of research on this, see "Mo & Tsai".
Note: you keep mentioning "free electrons" in the question. There are no free electrons experimentally. You put beam on metal foil, so they are bound to atoms, but you usually do these experiments at energies where atomic binding energy is irrelevant. (See E158 at SLAC, https://www.slac.stanford.edu/exp/e158/)
When one considers proper bremsstrahlung, that process goes as the target's squared charges, i.e., $Z^2$ from the nucleus. There is an atomic electron contribution that goes as $Z$ ($1^2=1$ for each electron), so the nuclear contribution dominates. When building lead glass calorimeters, the key ingredient is lead ($Z^2 = 82^2 = 6724 \gg 82$). This is why lead is ideal radiation shielding, yes the density matters (and the price), but really, radiation doesn't care about neutrons per cubic centimeter, it cares about $Z^2$ per cubic centimeter.

What you mean there are no free electrons experimentally? You could collide two electron beams or a electron and positron beam against each other in a vacuum (like LEP did).
This is the exact situation I have in mind: two electrons, in vacuum, with no external EM field, scattering each other, and without creating any new massive particles, just deflecting their trajectories.
This should be an elastic scattering, but if they radiate due to the change in the trajectories, then the electrons would lose some of their kinetic energy in the process.

@user2934303 I wouldn't consider part of LEP (or the ones I've used: HERA, SLAC, MIT/BATES), "free electrons".

I believe there is Bremsstrahlung in electron-electron scattering, but it is small at low energies because the dipole moment of a system of two electrons is zero in the reference frame where the center of mass of the system rests. Thus, there is only quadrupole radiation. See Nature volume 206, pages 922–923 (1965)
